# Bisher: Welches Tempus?

Tags: meaning, adverb, tense

Sind die folgende Beispiele mit dem Wort *bisher* richtig? Welche Bedeutungen haben sie? Kann man andere Tempora verwenden?

- Präsens: Bisher weiß ich das nicht.
- Präteritum: Bisher wusste ich das nicht.
- Perfekt: Bisher habe ich das nicht gewusst.
- Plusquamperfekt: Bisher hatte ich das nicht gewusst.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Präsens: In wenigen gesprochenen Situationen, um anzudeuten, dass das Gegenüber das vermutlich gleich sagen wird <s>, aber nicht soll:</s>

> Weißt du, wer im neuen Harry Potter stirbt?!?
>
> Bisher weiß ich das nicht!  *bös schau*

Perfekt: Die übliche gesprochene Form, nachdem man die Sache jetzt erfahren hat.

Präteritum: Dasselbe schriftlich.

Plusquamperfekt: Kann mir keine korrekte Situation vorstellen, da "bisher" durch "bis dahin" oder ähnliches ersetzt werden müsste.

Mit einer Zeitmaschine lässt sich vielleicht auch das Futur Exakt gewinnbringend einsetzen.

Comment: Grundsätzlich kann ich zustimmen, allerdings nicht beim Präsens. Da nennst du ein Beispiel, aber ich glaube, dass es eher allgemein um die *Möglichkeit* geht, dass man es gleich erfahren könnte, ohne dass damit eine Wertung einher geht: "Bisher weiß ich es nicht. Mit etwas Glück erfahre ich es gleich." Gleiches Prinzip, natürlich, aber genau gegenteilige Wertung. +1 für die Unterscheidung mündlich/schriftlich bei Perfekt/Präteritum, das ist mir entgangen.

Comment: Im Präsens würde ich "bis jetzt" verwenden. Bisher ergibt einfach aufgrund der impliziten Zeitandeutung (bis in die vergangenheit) nur mäßig Sinn. Ist wohl eine Geschmacks-/Dialektfrage :)
Ansonsten perfekt zsuammengefasst +1

Comment: Bei „mündlich/schriftlich“ würde ich aber mal leicht widersprechen. Soo einfach sollte man sich das mit den Zeitformen im Deutschen nicht machen.

Comment: @Debilski: Du bist herzlich eingeladen, eine bessere Antwort zu verfassen, ich werde sie dann auch gerne upvoten. Ich glaube, dass das obige korrekt ist, solange die Sätze nicht als Nebensätze, indirekte Rede etc. auftreten, aber ich kann mich irren.

Comment: Eine richtige Begründung habe ich ja auch nicht; ich denke, dass man prinzipiell alles sagen kann (also dass „bisher“ keine spezielle Zeitform verlangt) und dass sich das Problem damit im Grunde erledigt hat. Die Wahl der Zeitform ist also vom Drumherum abhängig und funktioniert eben wie sonst auch und muss dann vielleicht gar nicht weiter erläutert werden.

Comment: Und wenn man sie dennoch erläutert ist „mündlich/schriftlich“ eben nur ein Häufigkeitsindiz aber natürlich keine echte Begründung. Aber andererseits weiß man ja auch, was damit gemeint ist, wenn man das so sagt.

Comment: @thei: Es soll wohl "Im neuen Harry Potter" sein.

Comment: @Hendrik: Danke!

Answer (score 4):

Alle Beispiele sind richtig, auch wenn im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch *bisher* etwas häufiger mit den Varianten der Vergangenheit verknüpft ist, so wie es auch die Beispiele im [Goethe Lexikon](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/GWB?lemma=bisher) sind.

Allerdings sind im [Wortschatz Lexikon der Universität Leipzig](http://wortschatz.uni-leipzig.de/cgi-bin/wort_www.exe?site=22&Wort_id=22102&bl=2) wunderbare Beispiele
aufgeführt, die den Einsatz von *bisher* mit Präsens belegen:

> Denn der angestrebte Haushaltskompromiss dürfte auch ein Ende des Milliardenrabatts für die Briten bei der Finanzierung der EU bedeuten, was London bisher wütend und strikt ablehnt. (Quelle: fr-aktuell.de vom 03.01.2005)
>
> Dieses Versprechen konnte Bush nicht einlösen - weil der Schutzschild, wie Pannen zeigen, bisher unrealistisch erscheint. (Quelle: fr-aktuell.de vom 03.01.2005)

Answer (score 3):

Intuitiv, ohne die Regeln zu kennen, würde ich deine Aussagen so interpretieren:

- Präsens: Bisher weiß ich das [noch] nicht. Vielleicht werde ich es gleich erfahren.
- Präteritum: Bisher wusste ich das nicht. Habe es aber gerade erfahren.
- Perfekt: Bisher habe ich das nicht gewusst. Jetzt aber schon.
- Plusquamperfekt: Bisher (bis vor kurzem) hatte ich das nicht gewusst. Vor kurzem habe ich es aber erfahren.

Möglicherweise finden sich dazu genauere Regeln, vielleicht sind auch einige Varianten falsch. Allerdings beschleicht mich das Gefühl, dass die Unterschiede doch eher schwammig sind und im Alltagsgebrauch daher zurücktreten.